# Cron job not working as expected configured with Quartz-scheduler.net

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have few schedulers configured with quartz .net

- Every five minute forever: `0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *`
- Every five minute from Monday to Friday between 9:30AM to 3PM : `0 30/5 9-14 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`

First scheduler which runs every 5 minute forever works well without any problem.

Second scheduler expression (`0 30/5 9-14 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`) checked [here](https://crontab.cronhub.io/) and is valid expression- which should work from Monday to Friday between 9:30AM to 3PM is not working as expected

- Some times it is not getting started
- Some times it stops at 55th minutes and get restart at next 30th minute. Example: it started at 9:30 AM and stops at 9:55 AM and then again started at 10:30AM , stopped at 10:55AM , started back at 11:30 AM. and so on.

I wondered why second expression get stops sometimes.

Comment: 30/5 should mean on the 30th minute of every hour and then every five minutes afterwards up to but including the end of the hour. PS http://www.cronmaker.com/ is better as it you show you exactly the times it will trigger.

Comment: Thank you for response. you are right. Cron expression is wrong. I need to change cron expression.